# Finish not working on activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-6.0-marshmallow, activity-finish

I am trying to finish an activity. Code is being executed but activity still stays in background.

This issue only occurs on Samsung S5 with OS (6.0.1). Everything is working as expected on other devices.

Here is the code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AccessTokenReceiverFitbit.this, PairDeviceStatusActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        intent.putExtra("fragment_to_load", "wearable");
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
```

Please let me know what is the issue.

Comment: After the code is executed, is your previous activity visible in the task stack? When you press back from the new Activity, does it take you back to the old activity or does it close the app?

Comment: first do finish() and then start acticity

Comment: try this.finish();

Comment: @Queendevelopers try this but it did't help

Comment: @esmailjamshidiasl try this but it did't help

Comment: did you tried AccessTokenReceiverFitbit.this.finish(); ??

Comment: @humayoonsiddique what is the expected behaviour? Do you have code after the call to finish() that you don't want to be executed?

Answer (score 1):

With API 21+, you should be able to make sure an Activity is removed from recents by calling `finishAndRemoveTask()`. With older Samsung phones, this does not always work.

You can prevent an activity from being added to recents by adding `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` to the Activity's `<activity>` tag in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score -1):

Just try your intent with

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

If that didn't help, check your logs in logcat.

Comment: try this but it did't help